# JAXB : Unmarshal object with 2 name spaces results in a null value

Tags: java, null, jaxb

I am getting null value when i try to unmarshal XML file ,
I have created package-info.java class with 2 name spaces as explained below.
Please suggest how to fix this issue

**1. My XML file looks like below :It has 2 name spaces**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <saleResponse xmlns="http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <_type>saleResponse</_type>
        </saleResponse>
```

**2. i have declared package-info.java like below**

```
 @XmlSchema(
                    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,     
                            xmlns={
                               @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api"), 
                               @XmlNs(prefix="i", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
                           }
                    )
            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            package test1;   

            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**3. SaleResponse class is :**

```
        package test1;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

        @XmlRootElement(name = "saleResponse", namespace = "http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api")
        public class SaleResponse {

            @XmlElement(name = "_type")
            public String _type;


        }
```

**4. I am getting null value when i try to unmarshal XML file**

```
        package test1;

        import java.io.File;
        import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
        import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
        import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

        public class JAXBExample {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

             try {

                File file = new File("C:\\Ravi\\file.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SaleResponse.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                SaleResponse saleResponse = (SaleResponse) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(saleResponse._type);

              } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            }
        }



        **I am getting null value when i try to unmarshal XML file ,
        I have created package-info.java class with 2 name spaces as explained below.
        Please suggest how to fix this issue**
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` to `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the default `namespace="http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api"` attribute into your `package-info.java` and you can remove the empty prefix one also: `@XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api")`.

It should work as your expected, output is: saleResponse

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, namespace="http://tripos.vantiv.com/2014/09/TriPos.Api", xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix = "i", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package test1;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

For more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html